# How to make a join and search in data using codeigniter and Php

Tags: php, ajax, codeigniter

I make a join between two tables using codeigniter framework and this is my query:

```
public function SearchDataUnderCondition($firsttable,$secondtable,$data)
{

    $this->db->select("atm.* , tender.status as tenderstatus");
    $this->db->from($firsttable);
    $this->db->join($secondtable,'atm.id_tender=tender.id');
    $this->db->where('tenderstatus','1');
    $this->db->like('serial', $data);
    $sql = $this->db->get();
    return $sql->result();

}
```

I am using database model when is remove

```
$this->db->where('tenderstatus','1');
```

from my code operation done  and i get result but I want to  make search under this condition.  what is my problem?

Comment: What are the values of `$firsttable and $secondtable`?

Comment: first=atm  second =tender

Comment: Ahmed, can you please provide your tables definition? In order to answer your question I need to know at least what is the type of the column ' tenderstatus' .

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$this->db->where('tender.status','1');
```

I think, we can not aliases in where clause

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```html
public function SearchDataUnderCondition($data)
{

    $this->db->select('atm.* , tender.status');
    $this->db->from('atm');
    $this->db->join('tender','atm.id_tender=tender.id');
    $this->db->where('tender.status','1');
    $this->db->like('serial', $data);
    $sql = $this->db->get();
    return $sql->result();

}
```

Answer (score -2):

Using aliases (and also making sure you want and WHERE AND LIKE clause):

```
        $fist_table = 'atm';
        $second_table = 'tender';

        $this->db->select('aliasone.* , aliastwo.status as "tenderstatus"');
        $this->db->from("$first_table as aliasone");
        $this->db->join("$second_table as aliastwo", "aliastwo.id = aliasone.tender_id");
        $this->db->where('aliastwo.status','1');
        $this->db->like('serial', $data);
        return $this->db->get();
```

Comment: @ Kisaragi2 i traied your code and dosent work ,thank you

Comment: Alias is not the problem here. It is related to column type. I commented the main post.